# Is it possible to get the statements within a method in PHP?

Tags: php

```
function mainFunction() {
  functionA(5, "blah");
  functionB("ok", "whatever");
}
```

How to write a function `GetFunctions` that returns the functions within `mainFunction`?

How to call them with the parameters given in `mainFunction`?

How to call them as follows?

```
foreach (GetFunctions(mainFunction) as $function) {
  print "Calling function $function: ";
  call($functionA); // called with parameters(5, "blah")
}
```

Working in PHP 5.2.8

EDIT: OK, here's a more complete explanation. I tried to keep it simple to make it easy to understand, but apparently that wasn't a good idea.

The goal is to call each ***assertion*** within a given static method. I am writing a testing framework. Each assertion returns true or false.

I am calling the methods as follows.

```
$methods = get_class_methods('LibraryTests');
foreach ($methods as $method) {
    if ( StartsWith($method, 'Test') ) {
        print "calling: " . $method . ": ";
        call_user_func('LibraryTests::' . $method);
    }
}
```

The above code calls each method within the class, but I want to call each assertion individually and track the result (true/false). `CallAssertion` is supposed to call each assertion (such as `TestUnit::AssertEqual(GetFormattedHour(5), "5 PM");`). This is the method that I am asking about.

Here is the class:

```
class LibraryTests extends TestUnit {

    static $success = 0;
    static $failure = 0;
    static $total = 0;

    static function CallAssertion($assertion) {
        self::$total += 1;
        if ($assertion) { self::$success += 1; }
        else { self::$failure += 1; }
    }

    static function TestGetFormattedHour() {
        TestUnit::AssertEqual(GetFormattedHour(5), "5 PM");
        TestUnit::AssertEqual(GetFormattedHour(16), "4 PM");
    }
```

So, the question is, how to write CallAssertion?

Comment: Please don't do this, there are surely better ways to do what you are actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? There is a very (VERY) good chance there's a better way than this.

Comment: @NickC - yeah, it might be a bad idea, but you don't know the situation and there may be no other choice. Perhaps what he's doing is completely safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.

Instead, create a class and use reflection to get its methods.

Regardless, you'll want to figure out *why* this is necessary and see if there is an entirely different approach you can use.

(If this is for debugging purposes, you can use [debug_backtrace](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) to inspect but its purpose is not for calling functions as you have described in your question.)

Comment: This is not what he's trying to do.

Comment: Doesn't `debug_backtrace()` do the job?

Comment: He does not appear to be doing this for debugging purposes. Regardless, I'll add a link to it.

Comment: It does the job, even if it's recommended only on development.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, what problem are you actually trying to solve. To me it sounds like you're trying to inspect the call stack at runtime. If so, I'd suggest just using `debug_backtrace()` ([src](http://www.php.net/debug_backtrace)).

I wouldn't suggest using that function in production as much though, as it's a rather heavy hit on your code.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility would be to do a file_get_contents on the PHP file that contains `main_function`, then go through it to parse out `main_function` and the functions it calls. Of course, I don't know your situation so that might not work.

Comment: @drgomesp Why not? Seems like a legitimate solution to me. It might seem ridiculous based on a situation you've had before, but if I were to ask a question I would want any ideas I could get, and mine seems like a possibility from the info I have.

Comment: I agree partially with this solution. The main problem is that if you pass a non-constant value as parameter, it can't be solved to its runtime value. Depends on what question poster wants to do.

Comment: True, that's a good point. Again, I don't know enough of what is trying to be accomplished, input, etc.

Comment: Removed the -1 due to @Simon comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.token-get-all.php

Probably a bad idea, but good luck!